# How can I reduce the height of a swimlane in Microsoft Visio 2013?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-visio-2013

I am trying to reduce the height of a swimlane in Microsoft Visio 2013 using drag and drop as usual but it doesn't seem to work:

[image]

I then tried to change the height property in the ShapSheet:

[image]

but `31.7333 mm` seems to be the minimum.

Is there any other way to reduce the height of a swimlane? Its minimum height seems to be locked somewhere. I did look in the swimlane's container ShapSheet: nothing caught my attention but some properties are pretty esoteric to me.

---

Following Devid's answer, I unchecked the height protection for both the swimlane and its container, although it does sound like the solution it didn't help:

Swimlane's protection properties:

[image]

Container's protection properties:

[image]

Protection properties of the container of the container:

[image]

I use Microsoft Visio 2013 Professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 5):

I found the following on a another site and it worked fantastic!
"Swimlanes have margins.  Go to the "Cross-Functional Flowchart" tab, click margins, set to 0.  You can then reduce the swimlane to any height you wish."

Comment: A source link would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found this answer.

The clue is in the bottom line of the answer, and the workaround I used was to highlight all of the objects within the swimlane, move them outside of the swimlane (just by using the arrow keys) then drag the swimlane boundary to resize it as required.

This worked fine, plus the objects moved outside of the swimlane are still grouped together, so I moved them back into the swimlane again (using the arrow keys).

Simple solution that worked! Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Some shapes won't resize because they have locked attributes like height and width. To change this you have to Click on the [Developer Tab](https://superuser.com/a/805495/172416) → Protection → Uncheck protected attributes →  Resize the shape.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I unchecked the height protection for both the swimlane and its container, although it does sound like the solution it didn't help. I added some screenshots at the end of the answers. Here is the [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pljr8ohd02g6ems/feature_aggregation-with-option.vsdx?dl=0) if it can help diagnose.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt ok tomorrow I will download the file and check it for myself and see if I find a solution.

Comment: I checked it and made a new Swimlane and chenged the protection and resized it. So the problem is not the swimlane. I then checked your diagram and I think there are objects inside the swimlane which are protected. That is why it won't resize.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for an answer, but none of the stated answers worked. I ended up copying out the contents of my swimlanes, then clicked into CROSS-FUNCTIONAL FLOWCHART -> Page, and then I was able to resize the thing.  After doing this, my contents were missing. I pasted the contents back in, and happy end.

I did remote all the protected properties (as mentioned in another answer) and that did not work. However, they were disabled when I went through the process I described above.